# View behind Scaffold - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried a lot to get the behavior of the iOS project https://github.com/ivanvorobei/SPLarkController working in Flutter / Dart. I do not understand how to get another view behind the scaffold (holding also the bottom navigation bar). Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Behind the scaffold or behind the scaffold body? Either way, you can use a `Stack`.

Comment: @user1032613 Behind the whole scaffold holding also the bottom navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved with the help of `Stack`.

First layer for the buttons on the bottom:

[image: 1st layer]

Second layer for the main content:

[image: 2nd layer]

Then, you can wrap the `BottomNavBar` inside `GestureDetector` with `onVerticalDragUpdate` property.

**Complete Code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => MyChild(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyChild extends StatefulWidget {
  final double screenHeight;
  const MyChild(this.screenHeight, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyChildState createState() => _MyChildState();
}

class _MyChildState extends State<MyChild> {
  double val = 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          color: const Color(0xFF303030),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Button 1')),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Button 2'))
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Button 3')),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Button 4'))
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.ease,
            height: constraints.maxHeight * val,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 25,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                      title: Text('ListTile $index'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                    if (details.delta.dy < 0) { // If the user drags upwards
                      setState(() {
                        val = 0.7;
                      });
                    } else if (details.delta.dy > 0) { // If the user drags downwards
                      setState(() {
                        val = 1.0;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  // Create your bottom navigation bar here
                  // and not bottomNavigationBar property of Scaffold
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green.shade100,
                    height: 80,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screen rec]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your great input! Any solutions for the bottomnavigationbar, which is an element of the scaffold? Seems your solution is a level doing that resize on the body only.

Comment: The green bar at the bottom of the gif represents your bottom navigation bar. And I don't believe you can use bottomnavigationbar as part of the 'Scaffold' because part of Scaffold's role is to position parts in the right place, which in this case would be 'bottom'. As a result, BottomNavigationBar must be a part of the body.